# yii2 login page for advanced templet with admin lte and yii2-user extension

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

Has anybody tried using the AdminLTE Theme with yii2-user extension? The login to the admin page didn't work for me. I am using localhost for frontend and localhost/admin for backend. The frontend is working fine but I couldn't get it work for backend due to the AdminLTE theme. Any clues?

I suspect the issue is in the below code snippet. It is using the default SitController rather than the AdminController from the yii2-user extension.

The below code is from backend/view/layout/main.php

```
if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'login') {
echo $this->render(
    'main-login',
    ['content' => $content]
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below config in the backend main.conf fixed my issue.

```
'user' => [
    // following line will restrict access to admin page
    'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',        
    'as backend' => 'dektrium\user\filters\BackendFilter',
    **'controllers' => ['profile', 'recovery', 'registration', 'settings'],**
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I use yii2-advanced and extensions:

- authentication: "dektrium/yii2-user": "^0.9.14",
- theme adminlte: "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "^2.6",

all controllers and actions looks perfect, except *logging in, forgot password, registration, resend confirmation*.
those invoke the left, header, footer view as were logged in, even though must only call the main-login layout.

after the configuration in the *backend/config/main.php* added:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        'controllerMap' => [
            'recovery' => [
              'class' => 'dektrium\user\controllers\RecoveryController',
              'layout' => '@backend/views/adminlte/layouts/main-login',
            ],
            'registration' => [
              'class' => 'dektrium\user\controllers\RegistrationController',
              'layout' => '@backend/views/adminlte/layouts/main-login',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

then, display *login, forgot password, registration, resend confirmation* will appear clean.

Comment: can you annotate your code so it becomes more obvious what you've done?